# What is the fifth coloum in the output of "ip -stat neighbour show" stand for?

Tags: linux

Did some googleing and looked into the man pages, but didn't find specific answer for this numbers.

For Example,

```
# ip -d -stat ne show dev eth1 | column -t | sort -V
192.168.200.41  used    1034/4635/1032     probes  6                        FAILED
192.168.200.44  lladdr  00:c0:b7:xx:xx:xx  used    1037/1032/266            probes  1  STALE
192.168.20.5    lladdr  00:40:9d:xx:xx:xx  used    25080/25050/25021        probes  1  STALE
192.168.20.6    lladdr  00:40:9d:xx:xx:xx  used    25076/25047/25018        probes  4  STALE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a look at [iproute2 source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/ip/ipneigh.c), the fifth fields gives timer information on `ARP` cache entries:

- `X/./.` : Number of seconds since the `ARP` entry was last **used**
- `./X/.` : Number of seconds since the `ARP` entry was last **confirmed**
- `././X` : Number of seconds since the `ARP` entry was last **updated**

Those timers are notably used to manage stale `ARP` entries and decide when a new `ARP` request should be issued. Refer to [this insightful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511117/7350091) for more info about `ARP` age timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I used `strace` to check what ip-neighbour actually do. 
When I filtered `strace` output for numbers that was in output of `ip` command I found out that there is sequence of calls sendmsg and recvmsg. This messages are interesting:

```
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=36, type=RTM_GETNEIGH, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_DUMP, seq=1539003976, pid=0}, {ndm_family=AF_UNSPEC, ndm_ifindex=0, ndm_state=0, ndm_flags=0, ndm_type=RTN_UNSPEC}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_IFINDEX}, if_nametoindex("enp0s8")}}, iov_len=36}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0)
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=76, type=RTM_NEWNEIGH, flags=NLM_F_MULTI|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED, seq=1539003976, pid=15530}, {ndm_family=AF_INET, ndm_ifindex=if_nametoindex("enp0s8"), ndm_state=NUD_NOARP, ndm_flags=0, ndm_type=RTN_MULTICAST}, [{{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_DST}, 224.0.0.22}, {{nla_len=10, nla_type=NDA_LLADDR}, 1.0.94.0}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_PROBES}, 0}, {{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_CACHEINFO}, {ndm_confirmed=2192723, ndm_used=2186723, ndm_updated=2186723, ndm_refcnt=0}}]}, {{len=76, type=RTM_NEWNEIGH, flags=NLM_F_MULTI|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED, seq=1539003976, pid=15530}, {ndm_family=AF_INET, ndm_ifindex=if_nametoindex("enp0s8"), ndm_state=NUD_NOARP, ndm_flags=0, ndm_type=RTN_MULTICAST}, [{{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_DST}, 224.0.0.251}, {{nla_len=10, nla_type=NDA_LLADDR}, 1.0.94.0}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_PROBES}, 0}, {{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_CACHEINFO}, {ndm_confirmed=2192699, ndm_used=2186699, ndm_updated=2186699, ndm_refcnt=0}}]}, {{len=76, type=RTM_NEWNEIGH, flags=NLM_F_MULTI|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED, seq=1539003976, pid=15530}, {ndm_family=AF_INET, ndm_ifindex=if_nametoindex("enp0s8"), ndm_state=NUD_STALE, ndm_flags=0, ndm_type=RTN_UNICAST}, [{{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_DST}, 10.11.0.23}, {{nla_len=10, nla_type=NDA_LLADDR}, 8.0.39.3}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_PROBES}, 1}, {{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_CACHEINFO}, {ndm_confirmed=206484, ndm_used=206707, ndm_updated=202203, ndm_refcnt=0}}]}, {{len=88, type=RTM_NEWNEIGH, flags=NLM_F_MULTI|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED, seq=1539003976, pid=15530}, {ndm_family=AF_INET6, ndm_ifindex=if_nametoindex("enp0s8"), ndm_state=NUD_NOARP, ndm_flags=0, ndm_type=RTN_MULTICAST}, [{{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_DST}, ff02::1:ff4b:3614}, {{nla_len=10, nla_type=NDA_LLADDR}, "\x33\x33\xff\x4b\x36\x14"}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_PROBES}, 0}, {{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_CACHEINFO}, {ndm_confirmed=2192670, ndm_used=2186670, ndm_updated=2186670, ndm_refcnt=0}}]}, {{len=88, type=RTM_NEWNEIGH, flags=NLM_F_MULTI|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED, seq=1539003976, pid=15530}, {ndm_family=AF_INET6, ndm_ifindex=if_nametoindex("enp0s8"), ndm_state=NUD_NOARP, ndm_flags=0, ndm_type=RTN_MULTICAST}, [{{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_DST}, ff02::16}, {{nla_len=10, nla_type=NDA_LLADDR}, "\x33\x33\x00\x00\x00\x16"}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_PROBES}, 0}, {{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_CACHEINFO}, {ndm_confirmed=2192723, ndm_used=2186723, ndm_updated=2186723, ndm_refcnt=0}}]}, {{len=88, type=RTM_NEWNEIGH, flags=NLM_F_MULTI|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED, seq=1539003976, pid=15530}, {ndm_family=AF_INET6, ndm_ifindex=if_nametoindex("enp0s8"), ndm_state=NUD_NOARP, ndm_flags=0, ndm_type=RTN_MULTICAST}, [{{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_DST}, ff02::fb}, {{nla_len=10, nla_type=NDA_LLADDR}, "\x33\x33\x00\x00\x00\xfb"}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_PROBES}, 0}, {{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_CACHEINFO}, {ndm_confirmed=2192536, ndm_used=2186536, ndm_updated=2186536, ndm_refcnt=0}}]}, {{len=88, type=RTM_NEWNEIGH, flags=NLM_F_MULTI|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED, seq=1539003976, pid=15530}, {ndm_family=AF_INET6, ndm_ifindex=if_nametoindex("enp0s8"), ndm_state=NUD_NOARP, ndm_flags=0, ndm_type=RTN_MULTICAST}, [{{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_DST}, ff02::2}, {{nla_len=10, nla_type=NDA_LLADDR}, "\x33\x33\x00\x00\x00\x02"}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=NDA_PROBES}, 0}, {{nla_len=20, nla_type=NDA_CACHEINFO}, {ndm_confirmed=2192568, ndm_used=2186568, ndm_updated=2186568, ndm_refcnt=0}}]}], iov_len=580}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0)
```

When I tried to find numbers from `ip neigh` command in strace output I discovered that `ip neigh` displays ndm_used, ndm_confirmed, ndm_updated values divided by 100.

This led me to `man 7 rtnetlink`:

> Rtnetlink  allows  the  kernel's  routing tables to be read and altered (...). Network routes, IP addresses, link parameters, **neighbor setups**, queueing disciplines, traffic classes and packet classifiers may all be controlled through NETLINK_ROUTE sockets.  It is based  on  netlink  messages.

And later:

```
RTM_NEWNEIGH, RTM_DELNEIGH, RTM_GETNEIGH
       Add, remove or receive information about a neighbor table entry (e.g., an ARP entry).  The message contains an ndmsg structure.

       struct ndmsg {
           unsigned char ndm_family;
           int           ndm_ifindex;  /* Interface index */
           __u16         ndm_state;    /* State */
           __u8          ndm_flags;    /* Flags */
           __u8          ndm_type;
       };

       struct nda_cacheinfo {
           __u32         ndm_confirmed;
           __u32         ndm_used;
           __u32         ndm_updated;
           __u32         ndm_refcnt;
       };

       ndm_state is a bit mask of the following states:

       NUD_INCOMPLETE   a currently resolving cache entry
       NUD_REACHABLE    a confirmed working cache entry
       NUD_STALE        an expired cache entry
       NUD_DELAY        an entry waiting for a timer
       NUD_PROBE        a cache entry that is currently reprobed
       NUD_FAILED       an invalid cache entry
       NUD_NOARP        a device with no destination cache
       NUD_PERMANENT    a static entry

       Valid ndm_flags are:

       NTF_PROXY    a proxy arp entry
       NTF_ROUTER   an IPv6 router

       The rtattr struct has the following meanings for the rta_type field:

       NDA_UNSPEC      unknown type
       NDA_DST         a neighbor cache n/w layer destination address
       NDA_LLADDR      a neighbor cache link layer address
       NDA_CACHEINFO   cache statistics.

       If the rta_type field is NDA_CACHEINFO, then a struct nda_cacheinfo header follows.
```

nda_cacheinfo structure is defined in `<linux/neighbour.h>`

Comments in `<linux/neighbour.h>` are not very helpful if you want to know what this values indicates and I also failed to find it in the Internet.